# Wait until image dowloaded Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm loading a recyclerview with Firebase, but sometimes, if there are too many elements, the images take too long to load or they simply don't.
I'm looking for a way to know when the image has finished downloading (since it happens in the background) and proceed with the code.

I've wrote what im trying to archieve with some pseudocode, I don't know what is the aproach to take, any answers or info is aprreciated.

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference();
    Glide.with(context)
            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
            .load(storageReference.child("users/"+grupo.getUsuario()+"/"+grupo.getTitulo()))
            .into(holder.portada);
  //Here goes what im trying to pursue: a while that wouldn't exit until the image is loaded.

while(hasnt finished downloading);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Implement a custom target](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/targets.html#animated-resources-and-custom-targets) that overrides the onResourceReady or onFailed methods and trigger your custom event handling there.

Comment: Thanks James! I'll take a look at it